# Android Latest leanback library key issue

Tags: keyevent, leanback

I am using latest **leanback version 27.0.0** in my app. Now am facing few key issues which was not there in the older version 24.2.1. The issue is like this.

I have registered the key events. So every time when I press "OK" `buttons` with the remote `onKey()` method will be called. but when I pause my app by pressing android home and resume it again `onKey()` method is not calling. But on resume, the key will be registered only.This issue was not there when I was using the older version of leanback.

Thanks in advance.